# How do I delete duplicate rows in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have some rows in a MySQL database which are duplicates, except for their ID number.

For example, I might have this as two rows:

```
ID   | wordlist | category
845  | abashed  | confused
1800 | abashed  | confused
```

I want to find all of them, and only leave one.

Can I use SQL to do this, or do I need to write a program of some sort?

To clarify, I only want to get duplicates in the wordlist section.

Comment: if they are referenced in another table that would leave your database incorrect as you won't know which ID was referenced for a particular repeating word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with an outer join in the `DELETE` statement:

```
DELETE a FROM tbl a
LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT MIN(id) AS id
    FROM tbl
    GROUP BY wordlist
) b ON a.id = b.id
WHERE a.category = '<category here>' AND b.id IS NULL
```

This will eliminate duplicates (in the `wordlist` column) for only a specific category and keeps the one with the lowest `id`.

Comment: I do NOT want to delete duplicates in the category section. Just the wordlist section.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander, okay, took out the `category` field in the `GROUP BY`. Try that.

Comment: Oh crap, I deleted extra information with this than I wanted to. Wanted to only delete words that were duplicate within a given category. Not your fault, this was close to what I needed, I gave you incorrect information.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander, please tell me you wrapped this in a transaction and were able to `ROLLBACK;`... or have a backup somewhere =(.

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this on a life data

Comment: This list is for initial import, so I have the list somewhere. Luckily none of this is collected data.

Comment: What exactly is a JOIN? I'm trying to get better at databases and trying to find reading material about them.

Comment: @AndrewAlexander take a look at [*this*](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE your_table ADD UNIQUE INDEX idx_wordlist (wordlist );
```

Comment: "Duplicate entry 'agreeable' for key 'index_wordlist'"